# Obj-C How To Print an NSTextField as a string?

Tags: c#, objective-c, xcode, visual-studio, encryption

so I am building a message encryption application in C# and Obj-c using Visual Studio Mac and Xcode, I have a text field where the user types their password to decrypt the message. However, after trying several things, I an unable to print the NSTextField as a string to compare it to the password string which is imprinted into the text file.

I have already tried NSString * = [DateCreated stringValue];This did not work.

Code put into Visual Studio by Xcode after designing GUI in ViewController.Designer.cs:

```
[Outlet]
        public static AppKit.NSTextField DateCreated { get; set; }
```

Code for message decryption where attempting to compare password strings for decryption of message, encryption is working perfectly.

```
public static string Decrypted(string encrypted)
{

    DateTime creation = File.GetCreationTime(@"/Users/bopc/encryptedmessagehere.txt");

    string asString = creation.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");

    var created = ViewController.verify;
    if (created != asString)
    {
        var alert = new NSAlert()
        {
            AlertStyle = NSAlertStyle.Critical,
            InformativeText = "That is incorrect, access is denied",
            MessageText = "That is incorrect, access is denied",
        };
        alert.RunModal();
    }
           
    else if (ViewController.dtime == asString)

// This is where I am attempting to input the NSTextField, attempting to convert it to string called dtime.
    {
        byte[] textbytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted);
        AesCryptoServiceProvider endec = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
        endec.BlockSize = 128;
        endec.KeySize = 256;
        endec.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(IV);
        endec.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Key);
        endec.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        endec.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        ICryptoTransform icrypt = endec.CreateDecryptor(endec.Key, endec.IV);
        byte[] enc = icrypt.TransformFinalBlock(textbytes, 0, textbytes.Length);
        icrypt.Dispose();

        if (ViewController.verify == created)
        {
            return System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(enc);
        }
        else if (ViewController.verify != created)
        {
            var alert = new NSAlert()
            {
                AlertStyle = NSAlertStyle.Critical,
                InformativeText = "It looks like you are trying to fool me by using a key file that was not created for this message. Nice Try.",
                MessageText = "It looks like you are trying to fool me by using a key file that was not created for this message. Nice Try.",        
            };
            alert.RunModal();    
        }
    }
    return encrypted;
}
```

Any thoughts are appreciated, than you.

Comment: Have you tried: NSString *myStr = [DateCreated stringValue]; To check that you have it: NSLog(@"%@",myStr)

Comment: [DateCreated stringValue] should do the trick but you are also comparing string using == where you should be using isEqualToString or similar. Also, you do if ( x ) else if ( ! x ) in that same comparison. You can just do if ( x ) else ... there.

Comment: Yes I already tried these things they did not work. Thanks

Comment: I am wonder exactly where I would out this code? Sorry, new to developing for Mac. Thanks.